# How do I automatically in-place archive items in users' Deleted Items folders?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office, office365

We have an In-Place Archive set up on our Office 365 setup. We would like for our default policy to be to automatically IPA any item, including (and especially) in the Deleted Items folder, after 1 year. We've already attempted to create and apply a Retention Tag, but this did not seem to have any effect on the Deleted Items folder, just the stuff in the Inbox. Is archiving the deleted items even possible, or can you only just permanently delete them?

Comment: Hi, i'm here to confirm the progress of your thread, is there any update? If your problem has been fixed, you could mark the best answer or share your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook and Outlook on the web, personal tags with the **Move to Archive** action appear as **Archive Policy**, and personal tags with the **Delete and Allow Recovery** or **Permanently Delete** actions appear as **Retention Policy**.

And **Archive Policies** can be applied to default folders, user-created folders or subfolders, and individual items.(**Source**: **[More about personal tags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/messaging-records-management/retention-tags-and-policies)**):

[image]

[image]

You could try creating a new personal tag(Action: Move to Archive) and add it to the retention policy, then run the following command to address the MRM:

**`Start-ManagedFolderAssistant -Identity <MailboxIdentity>`**

Finally, you could select the proper personal tag in the archive policies in OWA.